# Data not Sending Until Socket is Closed

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost, boost-asio

I am learning some network programming and was recommended to use boost-asio. I did Daytime Tutorials 1&2 on: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html and wanted to modify it so that the server reacts to a client sending a serialized object then sends back results. I imagined using something like the following sequence with the intention that the client would sit in the handleRead loop waiting for the server to finish:

Server:
accept --> handleRead --> process_read --> perform action --> handleWrite

Client:
connect --> handleWrite --> handleRead --> process_read

However, when I do this, both the server and the client somehow get stuck in the read loop I have set up. This is expected on the client side, but the client should be writing and sending the data prior to getting to the read loop. When I break the connection on the client side or add a `socket.close()` to the end of the write function I wrote, all the rest of the server steps take place with the appropriate data having been sent from the client.

I originally thought this issue had to do with Nagle's algorithm being enabled, but adding

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option(true);
socket.set_option(option);
```

Didn't help at all. Am I missing something that wasn't in the tutorial as to how to get this data to send such as flushing the socket?

```
void myClient::handle_read()
{
    boost::system::error_code e;
    try
    {       
        for (;;)
        {
            size_t len = boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(inBuffer), e);

            std::cout << "Client Received: ";

            if (e == boost::asio::error::eof)
            {
                break;
            }

            else if (e)
            {
                throw boost::system::system_error(e);
            }
        }
    }

    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void handleWrite(T& t)
{
    std::ostringstream archive_stream;
    std::string tempString;

    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream);
    archive << t;

    tempString = archive_stream.str();
    outBuffer.assign(tempString.begin(), tempString.end());

    boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
    size_t sent = boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(outBuffer), ignored_error);
    std::cout << sent << std::endl;
}
```

I'm fairly new to c++ and network programming so any additional documentation is also appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the original program from the tutorial work? What have you changed?

Comment: Yes it does. I changed quite a few things but the biggest thing I was trying to accomplish was being able to send a message from client -> server -> client rather than just getting a message from the server immediately after connecting.

Comment: It isn't clear at all from your question. I suggest Isolating a minimal breaking change and posting exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you're stuck in your read loop. It doesn't exit until end of steam, and end of stream only happens when the peer closes the socket.

Comment: So how I expected this to work is that the server will be sitting in it handle_read() loop waiting to receive something from the client during the handle_write() portion, but nothing seems to get written during the handle_write() and the client ends up getting stuck in it's own handle_read() loop without sending what it wrote until after it breaks. Are you saying I have to add something between the client handle_write() and handle_read() to get it to send the message? Or what do you mean?

Comment: Data *does* get sent, but your read loop doesn't exit until end of stream or an error. This is a bug on your part. You need to do something with the data as it arrives.

Comment: The thing is, if it simply kept reading stuff and printing `std::cout << "Client(Server) Received: ";` then that makes sense but it just gets stuck on the size_t len = boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(inBuffer), e); line. 

I don't see how it would get stuck there not reading anything if the client did in fact write something. I added a line to print the buffer in the loop as well but that doesn't do anything until the socket is closed either.